# django.core.management.sql.sql_delete removed on django 1.11

Tags: sql, django, upgrade, deprecated

I'm upgrading django from 1.8 to 1.11 and this  imports are failing

```
from django.core.management.sql import sql_delete
*** ImportError: cannot import name sql_delete

from django.core.management.sql import sql_all
*** ImportError: cannot import name sql_all
```

I was looking for the  remove mention in the releases notes but  I couldn't find anything.
Does anyone know when were removed and any alternative to replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django 1.7+, the recommended approach would be to use `migrate` and `sqlmigrate` instead of `syncdb` and `sqlall`.

I don't think that the `sql_all` and `sql_delete` functions were ever a public API, therefore their removal didn't have to be mentioned in the release notes. They were removed in [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/7e8cf74dc74539f40f4cea53c1e8bba82791fcb6#diff-979c6bb8ce4d2d1ddd943b9f400747bb), which was included in Django 1.9.

Comment: Thanks for the commit reference, without these functions do you know how I could get a list of the DROP TABLE SQL statements for the given app and a  list of CREATE TABLE SQL, initial-data inserts, and CREATE INDEX SQL for the given module?

Comment: The [`sqlmigrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate) command is the closest thing I can think of, but that gives you the list of SQL commands for a specific migration, not for the app.